# I am not able to reach my sessions route, issue with my routing DSL code in my akka-http app

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am able to access the board route using:

```
wget http://127.0.0.1:9000/board
```

Now if I try and access my session route like this:

```
wget http://127.0.0.1:9000/session/getByToken
```

I get this error:

> --2021-11-30 11:56:12--  http://localhost:9000/session/getByToken Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1 Connecting to localhost
> (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:9000... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting
> response... 404 Not Found 2021-11-30 11:56:12 ERROR 404: Not Found.

What am I doing wrong with my route configuration?

Also, I want the route to eventually be called like this:

wget http://127.0.0.1:9000/session/getByToken/abc123abc123abc1234

How can I fetch a string parameter on the `getByToken` route also?

```
 val boardRoutes =
    path("board") {
        get {
        complete("board#index route")
        }
    }

    val sessionRoutes =
    concat(
        path("session") {
        path("getByToken") {
            get {
            complete("session#load route TODO add param for tokenId")
            }
        }
        path("login") {
            post {
            complete("session#login route")
            }
        }
        path("logout") {
            delete {
            complete("session#login route")
            }
        }
        }
    )

    val routes = chatRoute ~ boardRoutes ~ sessionRoutes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `path` attempts to match the complete remaining path and nested paths are ignored. Instead, you need `pathPrefix` as the outermost directive. `Remaining` extracts the rest of the path which can be used to match tokenId.

```
pathPrefix("session") {
  path("getByToken" / Remaining) { tokenId =>
    get {
      complete("session#load route TODO add param for "+ tokenId)
    }
  } ~
    path("login") {
      post {
        complete("session#login route")
      }
    } ~
    path("logout") {
      delete {
        complete("session#login route")
      }
    }
}
```

Also, `concat` chains the directives using a `foldLeft`, so it can be used as so:

```
pathPrefix("session") {
  concat(
    path("getByToken" / Remaining) { tokenId =>
      get {
        complete("session#load route TODO add param for "+ tokenId)
      }
    },
    path("login") {
      post {
        complete("session#login route")
      }
    },
    path("logout") {
      delete {
        complete("session#login route")
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: ok, so b/c I used path with nested path, the outer path was just "session" so it wouldn't match `session/getByToken` ?

Comment: Yes, only session was matched.